# What are the average masses of male and female astronauts respectively?

Tags: astronauts, astronaut-lifestyle

Considering that each pound/kilogram costs a vast amount of fuel to put into orbit/get to the moon or Mars, it might make sense to use jockey-sized people or even midgets as astronauts. They might be less likely to die of long periods of free fall, too. Then there's the reduction in food consumption, air, space suit size and mass and everything else.

So my question is what are the average masses of male and female astronauts and is it less than the averages (means) of non-astronauts?

Comment: Afaik the mass of the human body is not too much compared to the whole thing, so being small is probably not so important like for tank operators in the military.

Comment: @peterh Are tank operators small?

Comment: As far I know, recruiting into the military, tank operators are chosen from the candidates with smaller body. It is because a tank internal is not a luxury car. It is optimized to destroy other tanks and protect the life of the operators. To have a comfortable room for the operators to stretch is a no-issue.

Comment: From [Almost 90% of astronauts have been men. But the future of space may be female](https://theconversation.com/almost-90-of-astronauts-have-been-men-but-the-future-of-space-may-be-female-125644): "Women use less food and oxygen, maintain their weight better on restricted diets, and create less waste. In the words of Sally Ride, 'weightlessness is a great equaliser'."

Comment: [Why Women’s Bodies Are Better Suited for Space Travel](https://elemental.medium.com/why-womens-bodies-are-better-suited-for-space-travel-dc1e5513ae36): "Men’s eyes are affected more by zero gravity Scott Kelly wrote in his biography 'If scientists can’t figure out what’s causing those eye issues we just might have to send an all-women crew to Mars' Hearing sensitivity... is, also declines with age much more rapidly in male astronauts than it does in female astronauts, according to the 2014 NASA report And in general, women’s immune systems are stronger than men’s."

Comment: From [The Case for Sending Women to Mars](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/case-sending-women-mars-180953096/): "(Kate Greene) tracked the daily caloric expenditure of all the crew members. She soon noticed that women consistently burned fewer calories than men, sometimes on the order of 1,475 to 3,450. Women also ate less than men. When all food must be shipped from Earth or carefully grown on site, Greene thinks, this could make a difference for mission costs. Alan Drysdale, a systems analyst in advanced life support and a former contractor with NASA, supports the idea of selecting

Comment: ...for astronauts with smaller body sizes, including women. According to some figures Drysdale crunched, the smallest women in the NASA program require half the resources of the largest men, Greene reports" From Quora: [Is it cheaper to send a female astronaut into space? Women on average are smaller than men, by more than 10 kg. Every kg of mass costs thousands of dollars to send into space.](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-cheaper-to-send-a-female-astronaut-into-space-Women-on-average-are-smaller-than-men-by-more-than-10-kg-Every-kg-of-mass-costs-thousands-of-dollars-to-send-into-space)

Comment: See also NASA.gov's [Study Investigates How Men and Women Adapt Differently to Spaceflight](https://www.nasa.gov/content/men-women-spaceflight-adaptation)

Comment: Does it matter which years, or is any date range okay?

Comment: The empty mass of a Dragon is $\approx$ 4 tons. It can get $\approx$ 6 tons cargo to the ISS. If the mass of the 3 astronauts in it is 240kg or 150kg, I don't think it is a significant difference. Although the higher strength of the males is not an advantage in weightlessness. Afaik astronaut women are typically larger (compared to the human female average). It is probably not intentional, I think bigger women are better to pass the probably hard training.

Comment: @DrSheldon As long as you state date range, and don't cherry pick a date range to prove a point, I don't see a problem

Comment: @peterh " I think bigger women are better to pass the probably hard training". Really? I would have thought press ups and pull ups and so on would be easier for a small (low mass) woman.

Answer (score 3):

> is it less than the averages (means) of non-astronauts?

Very likely.
A [recent survey](https://news.gallup.com/poll/328241/americans-average-weight-holds-steady-2020.aspx) from the US (a country with a significant number of astronauts) reports average weight of adult males as 200 pounds (90.7kg) and 162 pounds (73.5kg) for adult females.

For comparison, the allowed weight limits for cosmonauts on Soyuz-TM (Mir, ISS) were **56 to 85 kg**, meaning the average American male is above this range. Soyuz-TMA (ISS) extended this range to **50 to 95 kg**

Answer (score 0):

Launch fuel costs are a microscopic portion of the total mission cost.  It makes a lot more sense to design all systems for human bodies within maybe two-sigma of the median , thus giving you a much larger applicant pool, than to worry about a few kg of launch mass.

Edit:
There is certainly something to be said for female vs. male on Mars missions if the observed difference in health during long periods of zero-G  remains valid.  OTOH, if one believes the initial missions will be one-way, there might be a lot of controversy over reproductive capabilities in the early colony.